# Is this a sound elephant offer?

Tags: analysis, chess-variants, sacrifice, shogi, unorthodox-pieces

In the following [dobutsu shogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%8Dbutsu_shogi) position, is Gc3xc2 a bad move?

```
  ABC 
 +---+
1|   | g
2|lce|
3|E G|
4| L | *C
 +---+
```

Comment: Shogi and variants are on-topic according to this meta discussion: https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-international-variants-on-topic

Answer (score 4):

It's not a sacrifice, it's a trade after 1. Gxc2 G*b3 and taking the elephant on a3 next.

On the other hand, since doubutsu shogi is strongly solved, you can use an engine/tablebase (e.g. https://github.com/fuzxxl/dobutsu) to set up and see the solution anyway. (I haven't done this, though.)